# Is there a meaning if instead of just calling the function in pseudocode one writes a return function (especially regarding CLR)?

Tags: algorithm, tree, pseudocode

Is there a meaning if instead of just calling the function in pseudocode one writes a return function (especially regarding CLR)?

e.g. is

```
if x == NIL or x.key == k
   return x
if x.key <= k
   return Tree-Search(x.left,k)
else 
   return Tree-Search(x.right,k)
```

equal to

```
if x == NIL or x.key == k
   return x
if x.key <= k
   Tree-Search(x.left,k)
Tree-Search(x.right,k)
```

Comment: Do you know what "return" does?

Comment: Pseudocode is not standardized, so it can use any convention that is agreed upon. Yet the common sense tells that the second snippet is not equivalent even if we take the convention where the last statement is implicitly returned, as it has a path where `Tree-Search` is called twice.

Comment: If your example is pseudocode, why did you tag it with C?

Comment: I am sorry I still don't see my mistake, the return value stops the call, but isn't it recalling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` is certainly needed. Presumably the quoted code is the body of the `Tree-search` function, so it would actually look something like this:

```
function Tree-Search(x, k)
    if x == NIL or x.key == k
       return x
    if x.key <= k
       return Tree-Search(x.left, k)
    else 
       return Tree-Search(x.right, k)
```

Now this function is supposed to return a node from the tree -- the node whose key is equal to *k*. If you don't use `return` then the function will not return anything (except in the case where the first `if` condition is true).

Secondly, this function calls itself: this is intended. It is a recursive algorithm. The idea is that if the current node does not match, then search each of the subtrees that are rooted in its children. And for that you can use the same function. This recursion stops when the current node has no children or is a match.

Both the code without `return` and with `return` make the recursive call. The difference is that the version without `return` doesn't do anything with what it gets back from that call: it completely ignores it. The one with `return` will capture the returned value and return the same value to its own caller.

Imagine the execution made several nested recursive calls, then you can imagine this state as a recursion tree where each of those recursive calls is pending; waiting for the deeper call to return. Let's assume the last one has `x.key == k`. In that case that particular `x` is returned. But it is not returned to the initial caller, but to the recursive caller which was waiting for the result. If the returned value is not returned again to caller that is up one level in the recursion tree, then *that* caller will not get to know about this matching `x`. So each caller must get back that `x` and return it also upward the recursion tree. Finally the initial caller will get `x` too.